# Moving subtab created by Box integration

Tags: tabs, integration, netsuite, box

I cannot find the "Box Files" subtab in the list when I navigate to customize the form. All of the standard subtabs are there but the Box Files one is not present. Is there another menu created by the Box integration where I can control the place where it appears in the subtabs? It appears all the way to the right and I would like to bring it to the 2nd position in the subtabs.

Answer (score 1):

The box tab is generated from a script inside the Box bundle you installed into your NetSuite account. Unfortunately, because you don't have access to the script that creates the tab, you won't be able to change the location of the tab.